# Tag synonym suggestion textbox is overlapped by "Suggest" button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-synonyms

Tag synonyms suggestion textbox is overlapped by Suggest button

[image: bug picture]

Example [link on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/table-valued-parameters/synonyms) (requires 2500+ reputation), also reproduced the same on Stack Overflow in Russian. I don't have other site accounts where I have 2500+ reputation to be sure that it affects other communities than Stack Overflow plus localized versions.

All major browsers on Windows have this issue: Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE.

Comment: Yes, in SOes happens [too](https://i.imgur.com/J2UbcLo.png)

Comment: @Glorfindel Does this happen in other than Stack Overflow communities? You have at least 6 accounts with 2500+ rep on non-StackOverflow sites.

Comment: Just checked and it happens here (on Meta Stack Exchange) as well. In my browser (Firefox on macOS) it's less visible because the height of the Suggest button and the input field are equal. On the regular Stack Overflow, it doesn't happen (for me) but it has a new responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS box models strike again!

The label, entryfield and button are arranged using a flex layout, with a width of 100% specified for the entryfield. Unfortunately, that width is specified under the assumption that borders and padding would be included - which by default they are not... So the *actual* width of the entryfield ended up being 100% + another 12 or so pixels... Overflowing into the button.

Adding a class that forces `border-box` sizing corrected this.

Comment: Looks like this caused at least [one new bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311005/add-and-remove-tag-buttons-are-vertically-oblungated)?

Comment: Unrelated, @shadow; but fix is incoming.