# Add and remove tag buttons are vertically oblungated

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, preferences

I realize that for many users this is the hottest time of the year, but the add and remove buttons on the preferences page are ...melting down :-)

Surely it's a LESS typo that can be quickly fixed!

[image]

Comment: Coincidence? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310980/158100

Comment: @rene most likely not... fix one bug, create 10 others. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard first hand experience ?

Comment: @rene every day experience, yup.

Comment: Dupe, but my question is more humorous :-D /ducks

Comment: Yes, more humorous but you should know by now that we hat fun here ... I am the final close voter ...

Comment: This has been fixed and the linked question above has been updated.